# Why would a SATA HDD be the only one unrecognized by a SATA dock?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata, dock, enclosures

I have 3 Western Digital Caviar Green hard drives. One 1TB, one 1.5tb, and one 2TB. I have a SATA dock (branded Kingwin ez-dock) and a 3.5" external enclosure from Acomdata.

All 3 drives work perfectly and are recognized in the Acomdata enclosure. The 1TB and 2TB work in the SATA dock. The 1.5TB drive does absolutely nothing in the dock.

I have tried it on Windows and Mac, with FAT32, HFS+, and no filesystem. This drive works just fine in the enclosure, so I know there is nothing wrong with the drive. Multiple drives work just fine in the dock, so I can only assume there is nothing wrong with the dock. The drive does spin up in the dock, so it's definitely getting power.  But after about 30 seconds, it spins down and does nothing for as long as I leave it there.

What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could simply be an incompatibility with that drive and the dock.  It happens.  Especially if Kingwin didn't make the drive - and they don't make drives as far as I know).  A firmware update (if that's even possible) could resolve it - the update could be to EITHER the drive or the dock.

Comment: Thanks, in the process of looking for firmware updates for my drive, I found that there are lots of issues with the WD15EADS-00P8B0 drive I have. It's been RMA'd to WD and I should be getting a replacement soon. Thanks!